# Force celery to use json in place of pickle

Tags: python, celery

I've configured celery to use json in the following manner:

```
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

However, when the worker receives the task it generates the following error:

```
ContentDisallowed: Refusing to deserialize untrusted content of type pickle (application/x-python-serialize)
```

Is there something I am missing that's undocumented perhaps.

Comment: Having the same issue, can you please specify your celery version and the way you trigger your task?

Comment: same issue with celery 3.1, trigger tasks without parametrs

Answer (score 3):

The problem is celery is accepting as `json` and while sending a task its sending content as `pickle` hence the error.

As mentioned [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/userguide/calling.html) while calling you will have to specify serializer ( which is `json` by default since celery 4.0 )

```
add.apply_async((10, 10), serializer='json')
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be resolved in the latest version of celery. I'm adding the link here for reference:

https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/8047ca9e818db8151dc6c80814600797ab94f5bc/docs/history/whatsnew-4.0.rst#json-is-now-the-default-serializer